# Can't get animation to work. Animator Setfloat error

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I am still new to Unity and coding in general so keep that in mind!
I have asked this question on the Unity forums as well but people have told me that the code should compile fine and that they are at loss so I'm hoping to find some answers here!

I'm trying to get my walking animation to play as soon as the parameter which i called speed > 0.1

I keep getting this error and after some Googling I still didn't figure it out.

```
Assets/Scripts/PlayerMovement.cs(28,26): error CS1061: Type `Animator' does not contain a definition for `SetFloat' and no extension method `SetFloat' of type `Animator' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Here's my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed;
    public float floatDown;
    public Boundary boundary;
    Animator animator;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Boundary{
        public float xMin, xMax, zMin, zMax, yMin, yMax;
    }
    // Use this for initialization.
    void Start () {
        gameObject.tag = "Player";
        animator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame.
    void Update () {

        //Basic left, right, up, down, movement.
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Jump");
        animator.SetFloat ("Speed", moveHorizontal);
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, moveVertical, 0.0f);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = movement * speed;

        //Clamping so Bubbleboy doesnt exit screen.
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = new Vector3
        (
        Mathf.Clamp (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position.x, boundary.xMin, boundary.xMax),
        Mathf.Clamp (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position.y, boundary.yMin, boundary.yMax),
        Mathf.Clamp (GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position.z, boundary.zMin, boundary.zMax)
        );

        //Using relativeForce to simulate floating down.
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) {
            GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddRelativeForce (0, floatDown, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `Animator` to `UnityEngine.Animator`?

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling it with Unity and not Visual Studio, for example? You see this error in Unity's Console?

Comment: This has solved the error! Changing it to unityengine.animator solved it, my animation isn't working though but i think thats fixable from here!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have a script somewhere called "Animator". If you've got project script with the same name, Unity will prefer your script over the animator class that is part of Unity.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering!
I made sure that i didn't have another Animator class anywhere or script so the problem still persists

Comment: Hmm. There's no good reason for it to be behaving that way then.
A - can you add some more information about your project set up here in comments? (Pictures of the asset lists/script names/etc)

B- What version of unity is this?

Comment: Here's an image of the inspector of the player which should be having the animation, and a list of the scripts I currently have:

http://i.imgur.com/CUtND9a.png

Answer (score 1):

Going by you're reference image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0qmX.png

You have errors on 2 scripts. From my experience working with unity, this can cause visual studio/mono develop to cause "fake errors".

The error given is most likely cause because one of the script contains an (non-related) error.

The reason why im thinking this, is because i've have compiled youre code in my unity ide, no errors came poping up. Going by the image you provided and knowing that Unity behaves wonky when you have errors in your ide, this is most likely the case.

**Edit:**

Oh yeah almost forgot;

If this is the case, you can easily notice it when you are typing in the IDE. The auto-completion(IntelliSense) should be messed up and giving the default methods.

Comment: This is probably it. Fake errors are pretty common in all IDEs, though I've never seen one across files.

Comment: From my experience, this error occurs when the script reference gets corrupted, not when you have compile errors. When you have compile errors in a script, it just displays in the editor as if it was a previous version of it.

Comment: If a script reference gets corrupted it should say "Missing script". This case it seems to be an error.

Comment: I fixed the other error just now and tried to recompile the animation code and I'm still getting the same error

Edit: the auto completion is giving me default methods though like you said

Comment: Strange, if you type  " **animator.** " in the method Update(), what does the code completion (IntelliSense) give you, please type out the first 3-4 results. If this doesnt include Unity's methods for animator its an IDE/Unity problem. Else its a code problem somehow.

Comment: .animation .audio .BroadcastMessage .camera